# Inserting an auto incrementing Primary Key into another table (to join with later)

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm pretty new to MySQL, and I hope i'm getting things right.
I've set up a database with 3 tables with columns as below (Primary keys are PK):

`Users` table

- uid (PK)
- username

`Directories` table

- uid
- path
- project

`DirInfo` table

- infoID (PK)
- size
- dateofcheck
- exists
- pathID

When I insert NULL values to Directories.pathID, I get a new pathID (auto increment). How can I then insert that same pathID to DirInfo.pathID ?

Will I have to run multiple queries to INSERT and SELECT to keep each column in each table up to date, or am I doing things wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last value allocated by an auto-increment column during an INSERT.  You can use this subsequently as you insert into a dependent table.

```
INSERT INTO Directories (pathId) VALUES (NULL); -- auto-increment
INSERT INTO DirInfo (pathId) VALUES ( LAST_INSERT_ID() );
```

Or you can set a MySQL user variable so you can use it repeatedly.

```
INSERT INTO Directories (pathId) VALUES (NULL); -- auto-increment
SET @pathId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO DirInfo (pathId) VALUES ( @pathId );
```